# RibbonGroup 'Custom Toolbars' OfficeID?

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon, outlook-2010

I want to get hold of the officeID for the custom toolbars group that appears in TabAddIns! I can't find it anywhere, please help :(

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That's only for legacy addins.

Comment: I have need of the ability to dynamically modify the ribbon UI in runtime, and as far as I know, commandbars are the only way to do that.

I'm merging commandbars with newer ribbon controls for fancy stuff :D

Comment: That isn't going to work.  There is some ability to change the ribbon at runtime; see the docs.

Comment: What do you mean that isn't going to work? I've been through the workarounds involving adding hidden buttons, and this frankly looks better.

The current method already works, but with the officeID it can look less wonky

Comment: You mean you're making RibbonXML UI and manipulating it through `CommandBars`?

Comment: I'm actually using ribbon(designer), but yes. I'm adding and removing commandbar elements through code.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Ribbon Designer objects show up in `CommandBars`.  If so, thanks for telling me!

Comment: Sorry if I was misleading, I just wanted to put ribbon controls in a ribbon group that appears before 'Custom Toolbars'. It's purely an aesthetic thing.

Comment: Oh; that makes more sense.  I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `GroupAddInsCustomToolbars`.

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3f2fe784-610e-4bf1-8143-41e481993ac6&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thanks! I had those documents once, lost them, and could never find them again.